# Initialize non-const static member variables in C++, through a static member function

Tags: c++, initialization, int, static-members

I am trying the following and getting an emulator crash between the two log statements. Is there something wrong?

```
protected:
    static int maxSize;
public:
    static void setFontSizeRange(int max) {
        Log("here %d->%d", max, maxSize);
        maxSize = max;
        Log("ok");
    }
```

I can get the log to reproduce the parameter but it crashes before outputting the static member (so the first log shown above would not work while it refers to that).

Thanks.

Comment: Which emulator? platform? environment?

Comment: Have you defined that static member somewhere? (notice difference between definition and declaration).

Comment: Griwes, you can see all my reference to the static member in the sample shown (later references exist but don't get chance to execute). @D.Shawley, this is Eclipse for Arm for Bada, running on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the static member.

```
class Something
{
protected:
    static int maxSize;
public:
    static void setFontSizeRange(int max) {
        Log("here %d->%d", max, maxSize);
        maxSize = max;
        Log("ok");
    }
}; // class declaration ends here...

int Something::maxSize = 0;
```

Comment: This one always trips me up, thank you. Working ok now, so much for the only `static const` may be initialized error!